# Why is instantsearch declaration resulting in a typescript error?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, algolia

When I try to run my code initializing an instantsearch instance and adding a widget, I'm getting a typescript error:

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(137,7): error TS1005: ';' expected.

The line is for the search.addWidget.

And the error happens write at the period in search.addWidget

Any ideas how to solve?

```
import instantsearch from "instantsearch.js";

const search = instantsearch({
  indexName: "test",
  searchClient: algoliasearch("XXXX", "XXXX")
});

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: "#search-box",
    placeholder: "Search",
    autofocus: false
  })
);
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: no, I'm still confused on it. Is pulling from instantsearch.js not the most up to date way to do this?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example of the issue on CodeSandbox? I didn't manage to reproduce it. That would help to better understand the problem.